# EDP exotic boundaries condtions

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

I'm trying to numerically solve Laplacian(V(x,y)) = 0 on a cross having Dirichelet conditions on two opposite borders (e.g. V(0,x)=-10 and V(5,y)=-10)  and having dV(x,y)/dx = const . dV/dy for boundaries conditions(bdc) on the two other opposite borders. 
Any idea on how I should proceed?

I’m planning to use NDsolve[] but as you read we are not here in presence of common bdc (neither Dirichelet nor Neuman) and so I’m stucked.

For the small story it corresponds to the Hall effect physic see this ref if you wish: Electric potential in the classical Hall effect: An unusual boundary-value problem; American Journal of Physics 66, 668 (1998); https://doi.org/10.1119/1.18931 Matthew J. Moelter, James Evans, and Greg Elliott

Here is the code I have up to now:

```
(* Region definition here it is a cross (also called Hall cross) *) 
\[CapitalOmega] = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, -1}, {3, -1}, {3, -1}, {3, 0}, {5, 0}, {5, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 1}, {0, 1}}];
(* Plot of the defined region *)
RegionPlot[\[CapitalOmega], AspectRatio -> Automatic];

(*Boundaries condtion*)
(* I use here Dirichelet conditions corresponding physically to a fixed eletrical potential at the right and let parts of the cross *) 
(* u[x,y] is a scalar function corresponding to the potential defined for  x and y being in the region \[CapitalOmega] *)
cond = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == -10, x == 0 && 0 <= y <= 1], DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 10, x == 5 && 0 <= y <= 1]};

(* Looking for numerical solution of Laplacian(u[x, y])= 0 taking into account boundaries conditons named "cond" previously *)
ufun = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian [u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, cond}, u, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]];

(* Contour plot of u[x,y] *)
cont = ContourPlot[ufun[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], Contours -> 50, ContourStyle -> {{LightGray, Thick}}, ContourShading -> None, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

This works fine !

Now here comes the tricky part where I need your help.
The "exotic" boundaries I want to add to the previous Dirichelet ones should be for instance of the form:

```
D[1, 0] u[x, y] == A* D[0, 1] u[x, y] 
(*A being a constant *)
(*for the top and bottom boundarie of the cross *)
(* top:  y\[Equal]1 && 0\[LessEqual]x\[LessEqual]2, x\[Equal]2 && 1\\[LessEqual]y\[LessEqual]2, y==2 && 2\[LessEqual]x\[LessEqual]3, x\\[Equal]3 && 1\[LessEqual]y\[LessEqual]2, y\[Equal]1 && \3\[LessEqual]x\[LessEqual]5 *)

(* bottom:  y\[Equal]0 && 0\[LessEqual]x\[LessEqual]2, x\[Equal]2 && \-1\[LessEqual]y\[LessEqual]0, y\[Equal]-1 && 2\[LessEqual]x\\[LessEqual]3, x\[Equal]3 && -1\[LessEqual]y\[LessEqual]0, y\[Equal]0 \&& 3\[LessEqual]x\[LessEqual]5 *)
```

Many thanks in advance for your very precious help.

Dan

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem. however, the paper you point to is behind a paywall and there is no code to play with. I think you stand higher changes of getting an answer if fix the mentioned issues.

Comment: I am not optimistic that `NDSolve` can solve this problem.

Comment: For a rectangular region, it should be easy to solve with finite difference method. If you make the questoin more specific (e.g. add the Mathematica code for the equation and corresponding b.c.), I can have a try.

Comment: @ xzczd I have tried to be more specific. Please let me know if additional info are required.

Comment: There should be no space between @ and xzczd, or I won't get the reminder. OK, so your real problem isn't defined in a simple region and FDM isn't that suitable…

Comment: @xzczd I would be happy to have it work with a simple rectangulare region.

Answer (score 2):

OK, let me add an answer based on finite difference method (FDM). The solved problem is the one stated in the linked paper i.e.

\begin{aligned}
&\nabla^{2}V =0\\
&V(x,H) =V_0\\
&V(x,-H)=-V_0\\
&\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\Bigg|_{x=0}=\lambda \frac{\partial V}{\partial y}\Bigg|_{x=0}\\
&\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\Bigg|_{x=L}=\lambda \frac{\partial V}{\partial y}\Bigg|_{x=L}
\end{aligned}

where $\lambda=0.2,\ V_0=1,\ H=1,\ L=1$.

I'll use [`pdetoae`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the generation of finite difference equation:

```
{λ = 0.2, V0 = 1, H = 1, L = 1};
With[{V = V[x, y]},
  eq = Laplacian[V, {x, y}];
  bc@y = {V == V0 /. y -> H, V == -V0 /. y -> -H};
  bc@x = D[V, x] == λ D[V, y] /. {{x -> 0}, {x -> L}}];

domain@y = {-H, H};
domain@x = {0, L};

points@x = points@y = 25;
(grid@# = Array[# &, points@#, domain@#]) & /@ {x, y};

difforder = 2;

(* Definition of pdetoae isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)    
ptoafunc = pdetoae[V[x, y], grid /@ {x, y}, difforder];

del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;

ae = del /@ del@ptoafunc@eq;

aebc@x = del /@ ptoafunc@bc@x;
aebc@y = ptoafunc@bc@y;

var = Flatten@Outer[V, grid@x, grid@y, 1];

{barray, marray} = CoefficientArrays[Flatten@{ae, aebc /@ {x, y}}, var];

sollst = LinearSolve[marray, -barray];
sol = ListInterpolation[Partition[sollst, points@y], grid /@ {x, y}];
```

Fig. 3. in the paper:

```
ContourPlot[sol[x, y], {x, 0, L}, {y, -H, H}, Contours -> Range[-1, 1, 0.05], 
 AspectRatio -> 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Fig. 4. in the paper:

```
ContourPlot[sol[x, y], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0.8, H}, Contours -> Range[0, 1, 0.01]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It should not be too hard to solve the problem mentioned in the body of the question with FDM. (Cross-shaped region is irregular, but not that irregular. )  But I'd like to stop here because <strike>I'm too lazy to continue</strike> I doubt if the conclusion about boundary condition in that paper can be generalized in such a simple manner.